# How to copy TFS branch?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2019, tfvc

I have a TFS repository on Azure.  I am using Visual Studio 2019.  I have a TFS branch under a Development folder.  I want to copy that branch and make changes to the branch copy, thereby preserving the original branch.  How do I do this?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "TFS" repository. There is Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC) or Git. You need to specify which one you are using.

Answer (score 0):

From the command line:

```
tf vc branch $/project/path/sourcebranch $/project/path/targetbranch /recursive
```

From the UI, right-click the sourcebranch and pick Branch from the UI, enter the target path and create the branch.

This will create a new folder in your TFVC repository with a copy of the sourcebranch. It will be parented to the sourcebranch as well, meaning any merges will go to the sourcebranch by default.

In some cases you may want to create the branch from a shared parent instead and cherry pick the changes from the current source. That will allow you to merge changes upstream without having to go through the current source.